# Banner using full div width without losing responsiveness

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a website using ASP.NET MVC5 and Bootstrap : www.devadelic.com

My problem is that the banner is not using the entire div's width to display, as you can see there are space on each side.

I tried :

```
.img {
     width: 980px; //div width
     margin-left:-20px; //because i don't know why it's not centered
     max-width: 100%; <= delete
     height: auto;     
     vertical-align: middle;
     border: 0px none;
}
```

Then my banner is displaying well entirely in the div but, it's not responsive anymore.

And I don't know what to do anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML aswell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should add "**margin:0 -20px**" to your class "**logo**" so it will become

```
.logo {
    margin: 0 -20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this one:

```
.img {
    margin: 0 -20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the correct answer. Why post it again?

Comment: Sir sir i already posted by my network was very slow ...now this answer is uploaded,.....

Answer (score 0):

Yo want to be using minimum-width not maximum...

```
.img {
     min-width: 100%;
     display:block;
     margin:0;
}
```